# SQL trigger, ALTER_TABLE, need the ability to change table in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databses, tempdblog and testdblog. I'm trying to figure out how, when i alter a table on tempdblog, that exact same command will be executed on testdblog, i don't want the rows transfered i strictly want the columns.

Below is what i have atm from a site, i've tried to add a "USE testdblog" but it errors back at me about "a USE statement is not allowed..." as well as "must declare the scalar variable @test".

The new column names could be anything, all i know is that it's not a "add this column to the end of the table", it's more like "add this column just before userdef0 column".

I store the SQL query it ran on the main database and try to re-execute it on the other table, it's just a matter of finding out how to change databases.

```
USE tempdblog
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [db_LOG]

ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @xEvent XML
      DECLARE @tests nvarchar(MAX)
      SET @xEvent = eventdata()
      SET @tests = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @xEvent.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)'))

      exec testdblog..sp_executesql @tests;
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `GO` commands in there. Once you have a valid dynamic SQL statement constructed (you don't right now), you should also try:

```
EXEC testdblog..sp_executesql @test;
```

Or just simply:

```
INSERT INTO testdblog.dbo.dbLog(columns) VALUES(...);
```

Comment: I cleaned up the trigger to remove the log insert because i can deal with that later. The trigger needs to replicate the same ALTER TABLE statement on another table in another database. From the changes i've made, when i go to run an alter statement i get "Unable to modify table. Incorrect syntax near &"

Comment: Try storing the command you're trying to execute in a table and examine it. Sounds like the command it's pulling is entitized for XML, e.g. `>` is changed to `&gt;`. You should never blindly execute code you haven't verified is in the form you expect.

Comment: PS this seems like a really expensive way to perform mirroring or replication. I assume you want to maintain identical schema but not the data?

Comment: That would be it, i currently have deletion triggers on all tables that move deletes to this identical database, but now whenever one of my users changes a field, the application adds/removes a column that pertains to the table. I would rather have this script do it (it's not very often) than have someone make a change and then wonder why the program starts to produce errors. You are right BTW, I did an insert on @tests and i get "ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD&#x0D;  test2 varchar(50) NULL&#x0D;"